# Database table design approch in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have created the table with these columns:  `id, day, start_time, break_time, break_end`.

but some other developer suggest me to create like this: `id, monday_start_time, monday_end_time, monday_break_time, monday_break_end` and so on......... for whole week, for better query performance.

but problem in second approch is that i have almost 32 columns table.
other than in my first approch  i have 6 fields.
**so suggest me which approch is better first one or second one and why??**

Comment: the other developers are idiots.  you dont even need the `day` column, just a `datetime` for the start and break times.

Comment: First one is always good. Managing 6 column is always better than managing 32...

Comment: @pankaj i need good explanation too

Comment: In the first approach u will need query only specific date. N u will get data easily. If u used second approach then u will need to specify which column should u get i.e it is monday or tuesday or any other day. In second approach u need to specify columns too... So used 5 or 6 columns n get data easily.:)

Comment: @Pankaj it day like (monday,tuesday) not date

Comment: what if you decide to not have columns for weekends ( as end user might not need it) and then later on they think lets work on Saturday and instead give off on Monday ? highly unlikely but design should not be data dependent !

Comment: @Muds i am managing day through rows. and off day values are null and they will be able to change it according to their needs

Comment: yea but iff you have 32 columns you cant do that .... I gave you a reason to feel why your approach is better

Answer (score 0):

Your initial project is ok, 5 columns are enough.
You could even use only 4 columns deleting the day column and using datetime format in the *_time columns.
Like someone told me K(eep) I(t) S(imple).